# Auto-typing passwords etc. into a Hyper-V guest is not working. What can I do?

Tags: autohotkey, hyper-v, password-management, keepass, autoit

I am running several virtual machines (Windows and Linux) on a Hyper-V server.

I want to use Keepass to enter passwords stored on my local machine through the Hyper-V connection into the remote machines. As this includes Bitlocker PINs and Ubuntu FDE passwords, a simple Remote Desktop connection is out of the question.

However, the keystrokes are not recognized by the virtual machines. I tried Keepass, Autoit and AutoHotKey without success. It works fine with VirtualBox guests though.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably caused by the fact that Hyper-V Manager is running elevated, so any program that has not been started as administrator can't interact with it.

Try running Keepass or your AHK/Autoit script as administrator.

Also make sure that the Hyper-V connection window is not in foreground when using the auto-type shortcut, as it will be forwarded to the virtual machine.
Either use a delay or configure Keepass to switch back to the last window before typing.

Comment: Running AutoHotKey script as administrator did the trick for me. (Note: I wasn't using Keepass, just sending text using Send.)

Comment: It helped with Keepass too. However, it always unfullscreens the VM and only actually works when the VM is not in fullscreen mode (when using enhanced connection).